# Check if Two Elliptic Curves have the Same Number of Points

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, isogeny

Given two elliptic curves $E_1$, $E_2$ over $F_q$.
Assume that the two curves’ order is unknown. Is there a way to tell if they have equal order without counting it?

Meaning, if $N_i(A_i,B_i,q)$ is the order of Curve $E_i$ ($A_i, B_i$ are the curve’s parameters in the standard form), how can one tell if $N1=N_2$ without knowing $N_1$,$N_2$.

One direction is related to Isogenies. If the two curves are Isogenous, then over finite fields they will have the same order. I also [saw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117466/how-to-know-whether-an-elliptic-curve-has-a-low-degree-isogeny/117576#117576) that the $l$-Modular polynomial is zeroed over the $j$-invariant of two curves if they have an $l$-isogeny. Meaning $\Phi_l(j(E_1),j(E_2))=0$ in this case.

But if I follow this direction, which options of $l$ I have to check? And how is computing the Modular polynomial for all $l$ options done?

Comment: counting means not using [Schoof–Elkies–Atkin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm)?

Comment: @kelalaka yes. One reason is that I’m interested in cases where q is unknown directly. For example when you know N=pq but you don’t know the factoring of N.

Comment: @kelalaka edited accordingly

Comment: What is $N$ and is the $q$ in the expression $N=pq$ the same one as in the base field $\Bbb F_q$ of the - i assume - known elliptic curves?

Comment: @dan_fulea I did some more edits to better explain. Suppose you choose two curves (eg by choosing some a, b) and you are interested to know if they have the same number of points over $F_q$. You only know a multiplication of $q$ without knowing $q$ itself. Here $N$ is some multiplication of $q$.

Comment: There is a collision in notation, i suppose, which makes the question hard to catch, answering it would be the second step after we have a clear question. The first line gives us two curves, $E$ and $E'$, say, slightly changed notations. Over the same field, same order. And this field has $q$ elements. They are given, as the above comment wants to do it, by fixing $a,b$ in the equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ (and the characteristic is maybe not two or three when doing so) for $E$, and some $a',b'$ for $E'$, $a,b,a',b'$ live in $\Bbb F_q$. So far we know $q$. What is $N$? I suppose $N=E(\Bbb F_q)$...

Comment: @dan_fulea tried one more edit. I apologize if the question was not clear. Thank you for your comments

Comment: If you can show that there is an isogeny between the two curves, it follows that they have the same number of points (you can find this theorem in at least Cassels' book). This need not help much for finding isogenies is a bit intricate :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks. This is the direction I was originally targeting. I know that over finite field if two curves are isogenous they have the same order. I also found that means the $l$-modular polynomial over the two j-invariants of those two curves is then zeroed. But should the solution then be going over all of $l$ posibilities? and what are those?

Meta question: Should I rephrase my question to be this? I was thinking its better to ask for my target and not specifically for this direction. But maybe its better to be as specific as possible here.

Comment: I tried to be much more specific. I hope this helps.

Comment: Now we have a completely new framework for some other question. And the notations do not sit again right. Please try (next time) to introduce the objects one by one. In this case, what are $A,B$? Are these numbers the same for $E_1$ and $E_2$. If the characteristic is already fixed, why do we bother to collect it in the notations. So what is $N_1(A,B,Q)$ and what is $N_2(A,B,Q)$ and what do these numbers have to do with $E_1,E_2$? Also, please be specific. Which is roughly the range of $q$, so that we still keep doable things in the focus? Is $q$ about $10^4$ or $10^{10}$ or $10^{30}$?

Comment: Sorry! As I said I did not know if to be general or specific here. 
Notation: $N_i$ is the curve order, as mentioned. It depends on the two parameters of the curves in the standard form $A,B$ and the finite field which is determined by $q$. $A, B$ are different for each curve, I’ll clarify this in an edit. I repeated the characteristic in the notation to reiterate the problem. 

I prefer not to limit $q$.

Answer (score 0):

I will say some words on the question. However, as it comes, it is too general and slightly unclear. So the answer is Yes and No. Here are the two parts.

**Yes:**
In very special cases, we can already predict the order of an elliptic curve. For instance, the following result of Gauss gives full information on the order of an elliptic curve of the shape:
$$
E(B)\text{ over }\Bbb F_p\ :\qquad y^2 = x^3+B\ ,\qquad\text{ where $p$ prime is two modulo three.} 
$$
Then there are $p+1$ $\Bbb F_p$-rational points on the above curve for every $B\ne 0$, so that $E(B)$ is not degenerated.
So for instance for the prime $p=101$, we have $p+1=102$ points on all $E(B)$ for $B\ne 0$. Some curves used in cryptography are members of special families.

**No:**
In some cases it is from the human perspective a pure luck that two elliptic curves defined over the same field have the same number of elements. So if the human eye is missing a hint on the way some curves $E_1$ and $E_2$ are constructed, there will be no chance to claim same order without counting. For instance, for $p=101$ there is the following statistic of the number of elliptic curves $E(A,B)$ defined by $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ realizing a specific order $N$, i.e. $\# E(A,B)=N$:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
N & \# \text{ of }(A,B)\\\hline\hline   
 82 & 25\\\hline
 83 & 50\\\hline
 84 & 300\\\hline
 85 & 100\\\hline
 86 & 100\\\hline
 87 & 250\\\hline
 88 & 300\\\hline
 89 & 100\\\hline
 90 & 400\\\hline
 91 & 150\\\hline
 92 & 500\\\hline
 93 & 200\\\hline
 94 & 200\\\hline
 95 & 200\\\hline
 96 & 600\\\hline
 97 & 150\\\hline
 98 & 200\\\hline
 99 & 400\\\hline
100 & 375\\\hline
101 & 100\\\hline
102 & 700\\\hline
103 & 100\\\hline
104 & 375\\\hline
105 & 400\\\hline
106 & 200\\\hline
107 & 150\\\hline
108 & 600\\\hline
109 & 200\\\hline
110 & 200\\\hline
111 & 200\\\hline
112 & 500\\\hline
113 & 150\\\hline
114 & 400\\\hline
115 & 100\\\hline
116 & 300\\\hline
117 & 250\\\hline
118 & 100\\\hline
119 & 100\\\hline
120 & 300\\\hline
121 & 50\\\hline
122 & 25\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Now somewhere in the list is the number $N=91$ with the "complicated factorization" $91=7\cdot 13$, which is unknown. But this information is hard to use or connect with two individual curves among the many of them realizing this order. For instance $y^2=x^3+3x+6$ and $y^2=x^3+3x+7$. Why should these curves have the same rank?

Comment: Thank you @dan_fulea for all your comments and answer. 
I did refine the question. I have a specific direction in mind based on other questions I saw. But I was not sure if I should limit the question to this direction or present the general target. I tried being more specific now, I hope it helps.